# Problems when using Mockito and JUnit for testing in Java Project

Tags: java, unit-testing, junit, mockito, java.util.scanner

I have some problems when testing with mockito and JUnit, I want to test a method that take data from user input. When I use `String id = "E833462"`, the test function work correctly, but when I replace it with my generate function, the registerAccountTest() will be blocked at line `when(mockScanner.nextLine()).thenReturn(id, name, bd, role, sex, password);` And I don't know why. Although both ways are a String with an ID. I tested my generate function, and it still can create a random unique ID. Can someone help me to solve this? Thank you for reading my problem and trying to figure it out to help me.

Here is my test method

```
@Test
    void registerAccountTest() {
        Employee em = employees.searchById("E160052");

//        String id = "E833462";
        String id = Inputter.generateUniqueId("E", 6, employees);
        String name = "Test";
        String role = "MA";
        String sex = "Male";
        String bd = "08/03/2000";
        String password = "123456";

        String combinedUserInput =
                id + System.lineSeparator() + name + System.lineSeparator() + role + System.lineSeparator() + sex + System.lineSeparator() + bd + System.lineSeparator() + password;
        System.out.println(combinedUserInput);
        InputStream inputStream = new ByteArrayInputStream(combinedUserInput.getBytes());
        System.setIn(inputStream);

        Scanner mockScanner = spy(Inputter.scanner);
        System.out.println("Before when statement");
        when(mockScanner.nextLine()).thenReturn(id, name, bd, role, sex, password);
        System.out.println("After when statement");

        Executor.registerAccount(employees, em);

        Employee emTest = employees.searchById(id);
        assertNotEquals(null, emTest);
        assertEquals(name, emTest.getName());
        assertEquals(bd, emTest.getBirthdate().format(Inputter.formatterHalf));
        assertEquals(role, emTest.getRole());
        assertEquals(sex, emTest.getSex());

        employees.deleteOne(emTest);
    }
```

Here is my generate Id function in Inputter class

```
public class Inputter {
    public static Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
    public static String generateUniqueId(String prefix, int len, ObjectList ol) {
        String id;

        do {
            int num = (int) random.nextDouble(Math.pow(10, len));
            id = prefix + String.format("%03d", num);
        } while (!Objects.isNull(ol.searchById(id)));

        return id.trim();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The `spy` call doesn't change the `Scanner` object, it creates a wrapper. That wrapper exists only in your test. You need to replace the `Scanner` in class `Inputter` instead. It's easiest to do that in `@BeforeEach`, so you can restore it in `@AfterEach`.

```java
private Scanner originalScanner;
private Scanner mockScanner;

@BeforeEach
void mockScanner() {
    originalScanner = Inputter.scanner;
    mockScanner = spy(originalScanner);
    Inputter.scanner = mockScanner;
}

@AfterEach
void resetScanner() {
    Input.scanner = originalScanner;
}

@Test
void registerAccountTest() {
   ...
    System.setIn(inputStream);

    System.out.println("Before when statement");
    when(mockScanner.nextLine()).thenReturn(id, name, bd, role, sex, password);
    System.out.println("After when statement");
    ...
}
```

---

As an alternative you can use [JUnit Pioneer](https://junit-pioneer.org/docs/standard-input-output/). It allows you to easily replace the results of `System.in` without any manual setup. It also allows you to read what's been written to `System.out` and `System.err`.